# How to reduce the access time in a vector

Tags: c, caching, gcc, instruments

I´m trying to increase an algorithm speed, So I ran my application with "Instruments" for iOS, the results, almost 75% of time is used to save the calculations in a vector.

Does anyone know a better way to save the data without consuming so quantity of CPU? I suppose is related with the access to cache memory or something like that. The line is marked with a comment, in this line is saved a short in an array of shorts.

```
short XY[32*32*2]
Mat _XY(bh, bw, CV_16SC2, XY), matA;
Mat dpart(dst, Rect(x, y, bw, bh));

for( y1 = 0; y1 < bh; y1++ )
{
    short* xy = XY + y1*bw*2;
    int X0    = M[0]*x + M[1]*(y + y1) + M[2];
    int Y0    = M[3]*x + M[4]*(y + y1) + M[5];
    float W0  = M[6]*x + M[7]*(y + y1) + M[8];

    M2[2] = X0;
    M2[3] = Y0;

    for(x1=0; x1<bw; x1++)
    {

        float W      = W0 + M[6]*x1;
        W            = 1./W;
        float x12[2] = {x1*W,W};


        matvec2_c(M2,x12,M3);
        short aux    = (M3[0]);
        int aux2     = x1*2;
        xy[aux2]     = aux;          // %60 CPU TIME
        xy[x1*2+1]   = (M3[1]);      // 11% CPU TIME
    }
    // ...
}

void matvec2_c(float m[4], float v[2], float d[2])
{
    d[0] = m[0]*v[0] + m[2]*v[1];
    d[1] = m[1]*v[0] + m[3]*v[1];
}
```

Comment: You are accessing `xy` in linear order; you can't do much better than that from a cache point of view!  What is the complexity of `matvec2_c`?  It sounds like a matrix-vector multiply; if so, I struggle to believe that you're memory-bound.

Comment: `short* xy = XY + y1*bw*2;` seems a bit strange. are you calculating memory offsets there?

Comment: maybe the alignment of rows and columns are not C but Fortran style? I guess we need more information about your matrix type.

Comment: Edited the question with the matrix lenght and type, also I included the matvec2_c

Comment: Try `int` instead of `short`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was the best I could do it:

```
short XY[32*32*2];
int XYI[32*32*2];
Mat _XY(bh, bw, CV_16SC2, XY), matA;
Mat _XYI(bh, bw, CV_32S, XYI);
Mat dpart(dst, Rect(x, y, bw, bh));

 for( y1 = 0; y1 < bh; y1++ )
 {
    int * xyi = XYI + y1*bw;
    short * xy = XY + y1*bw*2;

    int X0 = M[0]*x + M[1]*(y + y1) + M[2];
    int Y0 = M[3]*x + M[4]*(y + y1) + M[5];

    float W0 = M[6]*x + M[7]*(y + y1) + M[8];
    M2[2]=X0;
    M2[3]=Y0;

    for(x1=0;x1<bw;x1++){

    float W = W0 + M[6]*x1;
    W= 1./W;
    float x12[2]={x1*W,W};


    matvec2_c(M2,x12,M3);

    xyi[x1*2] = (M3[0]);//9% 
    xyi[x1*2+1]=(M3[1]);//6%



}
for(x1=0;x1<bw;x1++){

  xy[x1*2] = xyi[x1*2];//4%
  xy[x1*2+1]=xyi[x1*2+1];//3%
}
```

I just split the part where the code saves the equation in two parts, so I suppose it is something related with the way the cpu acces to the cache or maybe something related with the different formats.
The algorithm time decrease from 93 ms to 78 ms.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is it is a compiler-optimization-issue: the pointer calculation for xy is done within the for(x1= -loop and not in the for(y1= -loop, so it gets done many more times than necessary.

Possible solution: use `assert()` to force instantiation:

```
#include <assert.h>

...
short* xy = XY + y1*bw*2;
assert (xy!=NULL);
...
```

Comment: @Gustavo: It would be interesting know what you did to solve it. Put what you did in an answer & accept it ;), even if it entails a redesign of your algorithm - others will learn from it as well.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what your code does, it is not really writtin maintainer friendly. But if you are accessing data in those arrays in all directions (left, top, right, down), then the following might be for you.

Index your array using *[Morton Code / Z order curve.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morton_code)*. It increases the [locality of reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality_of_reference), which gives better caching behaviour when you are accessing elements fully around elements.

Think about it: Using classic 2d indexing, the distance to the top and bottom neighbours is the pitch or width. If your width/pitch is very high, then you are accessing very distant elements of your array. Considering that CPU do a lot of speculative caching, a lot of these speculations result in wasted efforts (so called [cache-miss](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_miss#Cache_miss)). You have some good indices (the left and right neighbours), and some very, very bad (the top and bottom neighbours).

With Morton indexing, you don't have ideal left/right neighours, but equally, you do not have distant top/bottom neighbours.

If on average, you *do* hit the cached data, then accessing these data is really cheap (data might already be in cache before you even start accessing it, thanks to [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speculative_execution](speculative execution) and [prefetching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prefetching).

Of course, if most of your code accesses the elements in left-to-right order, or if this is not a relevant bottleneck, you might not want to do this.